# MSSQL select during tranascation, get data as it was before the transaction started

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I run services that updates various SQL tables using transactions. Some of the transactions take several minutes to run before the changes are committed.

Now i'm building an application that only reads from these tables, and currently the transactions lock the tables. I can query using WITH (NOSELECT):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WITH (NOSELECT)
```

`NOSELECT` howerver seems to be the same as `READ UNCOMMITTED` as i get the uncommitted changes.

I want to get the data in it's state as it was before the transaction started, when i query during a transaction. It seems to be default behaviour in MySql but not in MSSQL.

How can i accomplish this? ISOLATION LEVELS seems to only be how transactions work in paraparallelllell with eachother.

Comment: You could try turning [snapshot isolation on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) for your database.

Comment: That worked, thank you